# How to find the kind of subview object the view is containing in it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios6.1

I am trying to find a specific class object added as **Subview** to a **UIView**, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for(UIView *aView in yourView.subviews){
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]){
       //YourClass found!!
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve when there are several same type Views, like UILabel in the subviews. try to add tag on the view, and use viewWithTag to access the subview later.

Answer (score 3):

for example if you are finding an object of type UILabel class than it is shown as below.

```
for (UIView *subView in [weeklyViewA subviews]) {
            if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                NSLog(@"label class :: %@", [subView description]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift answer**

For this case, I think we can use Swift's `first.where` syntax, which is more efficient than `filter.count`, `filter.isEmpty`.

Because when we use `filter`, it will create a underlying array, thus not effective, imagine we have a large collection.

So just check if a view's `subViews` collection contains a specific kind of class, we can use this

```
let containsBannerViewKind = view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is BannerView }) != nil
```

which equivalent to: find me the first match to BannerView class in this view's subViews collection. So if this is true, we can carry out our further logic.

**Reference**: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Rules.md#first-where

Answer (score 0):

This is the swift version for checked solution :

Example for UITextField :

```
    for (_, view) in self.myView.subviews.enumerate(){
        if view.isKindOfClass(UITextField){
            //Here we go
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion.`isMemberOfClass:`is better than `isKindOfClass:`,for example:

```
for (BadgeButton *button in self.subviews) {
    if ([button isMemberOfClass:[BadgeButton class]]) {
        button.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16152363)

Comment: @JonRose Yeah,I had improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2:
You can try below code:

```
let allsubviews = self.view.subviews
allsubviews.forEach { (view) in
   if view.isKind(of: UIScrollView.self){
       //current view is UIScrollview
   }
}
```